# Laravel insert multi array to mysql

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple arrays that I need to insert into mysql with PHP laravel.

Data it show like this

```
 count: (2) [2, 1]
 description: (2) [Array(0), Array(2)]
 id_male: (2) [38, 27]
 id_resturant: 5
 pay: "cash"
 price: 76
 status: 1
 title: (2) ["pepsi", "piza"]
```

count, id_male , title array i need insert it each male in different row.

Description multi array I will insert it implde

Code in php

```
    $dataa = $request->all();
    $title = $dataa['title'];
    $count = $dataa['count']; 

    foreach ($title as $key => $input) {
        $data = new Order;
        $data->title = isset($title[$key]) ? $title[$key] : ''; //add a default value here
        $data->description = $request->description;
        $data->id_user  = Auth::id();
        $data->count = $request->count;
        $data->id_male = $request->id_male;
        $data->id_resturant = $request->id_resturant;
        $data->status = $request->status;
        $data->price = $request->price;
        $data->note = $request->note;
        $data->pay = $request->pay;
        $data->uuid = $randomNumber;
        $data->save();        
        return response()->json([
            'data'=>$data,
            'state'=>true,
            'msg'=>''
        ]);
    }
```

It's not working !

Comment: Make __sure__ that you understand what does `return` do.

Comment: it's api for ionic 4

Comment: `return` does not care whether it is ionic, react or whatever.

Comment: my problem with code insert not return

Comment: Your problem is that you don't understand what your code do.

Comment: Please explain in details. Not working means is there any error? If so please share that too.

Answer (score 1):

I applaud @u_mulder. You, sir, deserve reputation gain on those comments.

@OP, You have to put `return` outside of `foreach` loop...

> If called from within a function, the `return` statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. `return` also ends the execution of an `eval()` statement or script file.

```
$dataa = $request->all();
$title = $dataa['title'];
$count = $dataa['count']; 

foreach ($title as $key => $input) {
    ...       
}

return response()->json([
    'data'=>$data,
    'state'=>true,
    'msg'=>''
]);
```

If you want all `Order` entities to be returned after the loop finished processing, add them in to a special array, for example:

```
$dataa = $request->all();
$title = $dataa['title'];
$count = $dataa['count']; 

$dataToReturn = [];

foreach ($title as $key => $input) {
    $data = new Order;
    ...
    $dataToReturn[] = $data;
}

return response()->json([
    'data'=>$dataToReturn,
    'state'=>true,
    'msg'=>''
]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that last order `$data` should be returned as json. Probably OP wants them all or none.

Comment: Valid point, thx

Comment: "Array to string conversion !!

Comment: I'm not as knowledgable in laravel. But I'm sure you can take a look at docs and see how exactly data are to be returned.

Comment: thank u i solved it

Comment: @MahmoudSehsah If this answer helped you please mark it as the correct answer. This could help others.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto first thank u for your help , but i solved it by change code from database